# Как добавить созданный средствами JS тег в список в коде HTML

Tags: javascript

```js
let newLi = document.createElement("li");
newLi.classList.add('menu-item');
newLi.innerText = 'Пятый пункт';
// console.log(newLi); Ok
// console.log(menu); Ok
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
     <nav>
       <ul class="menu">
         <li class="menu-item">Первый пункт</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Третий пункт</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Второй пункт</li>
         <li class="menu-item">Четвертый пункт</li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
   </header>
</body>
```

**Помогите подобрать подходящий метод добавить созданный средствами JS тег в список ul > li на соответствующую позицию.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let newLi = document.createElement("li");
newLi.classList.add('menu-item');
newLi.innerText = 'Пятый пункт';
document.querySelector('nav>ul.menu').appendChild(newLi);
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">Первый пункт</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Третий пункт</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Второй пункт</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Четвертый пункт</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```